# Do not align PHP with HTML - separate indentations : how?

Tags: php, html, coding-style, phpstorm

In php templates, I like my PHP and HTML codes to have separate indentations, I find it more readable.

But PHPStorm always aligns them automaticly when I press enter ; and I'm so sad.

What I'd like:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <section>
      <ul>
<?php
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
?>
        <li><?php echo $post['title'] ?></li>
<?php
  }
<?>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I don't:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <section>
      <ul>
      <?php
      foreach ($posts as $post) {
      ?>
        <li><?php echo $post['title'] ?></li>
      <?php
      }
      <?>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Does `Project Settings -> Code Style -> PHP` exist? If so, is there an option there that you can use?

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't seem so. Nothing to manage the relation between HTML and PHP.

Comment: @theredled, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't... Maybe I should write a ticket on their Bug Tracker, even if I'm the only one interested in that feature...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a macro in PHPstorm and define exactly what/how you want it formated:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Comment: Can a macro change the way PHPStorm automaticly indents (while you're typing), without explicitly launching that macro ?

Comment: Well, if you want it to be automatic, you'll have to edit the configuration. Try looking the the config folders: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs